# UltiSnips not working with VimWiki

Tags: vimrc, plugin-ultisnips, plugin-vimwiki

I have been trying to make UltiSnips work with VimWiki to no avail, as they share mappings for expand snippet/next link (on `<tab>`).

I tried setting VimWiki's bindings to something else by using the following, which sadly didn't work, as the snippets didn't expand:

```
" vimwiki plugin settings
filetype plugin on
let g:vimwiki_list = [{'path': '~/Wiki/', 'syntax': 'markdown', 'ext': '.md'}]
nmap <C-j> <Plug>VimwikiNextLink
nmap <C-k> <Plug>VimwikiPrevLink

" ultisnips plugin settings
let g:UltiSnipsSnippetsDir=$HOME.'/.vim/UltiSnips/'
let g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories=["UltiSnips"]

let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger="<tab>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger="<s-tab>"
```

The link to my entire vimrc can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/nB795hDp).

If I set UltiSnips' expand trigger to anything else (like `<c-j>`), it works without a problem, but I am quite used to expanding on `<tab>` from other apps that I use.

Is there anything I can do to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this issue can be found in [this thread](https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki/issues/357).

The only thing one has to do is to add this line to `~/.vimrc`, which allows to both use Tab in normal mode to cycle through links, and to expand links in Insert mode:

`let g:vimwiki_table_mappings = 0`

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix my vimwiki ultisnippets by changing the vimwiki file extension to `.mdvimwiki` and registering it with @ranebrown the `UltisnipsAddFiletypes` tip.

**I did not need** the `let g:vimwiki_table_mappings = 0`.

This is what I added to my vim.init:

```
autocmd FileType mdvimwiki UltiSnipsAddFiletypes vimwiki

" use my custom folder, markdown syntax and custom extension
let g:vimwiki_list = [{'path': '~/.config/mynotes/',
                    \ 'syntax': 'markdown', 'ext': '.mdvimwiki'}]
```